# ¿AppCenter eliminó la opción de 'push notification'?

Tags: windows-forms, xamarin, push-notification

Estoy intentando implementar notificaciones en mi aplicación móvil hecho en xamarin forms con appcenter; pero viendo la documentación y tutoriales me dicen que vaya a la sección de **push** y en la interfaz de appcenter que veo no existe esa opción.[image: como verán solo me sale estas opciones]

En la [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/service-config) de microsoft me dice que hya una opción de **push**
como en la opción 3[image: imagen donde dice que seleccione la opción **push** que en mi interfaz no veo]

Comment: La opcion no fue Eliminada, ya pudiste llevarlo a cabo?

Comment: Pero recomiendan migrar a azure notification hub porque esa caracteristica esta desapareciendo. lo que hice fue usar OneSignal